# Adding Unicode beside divs

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS code below of some data displayed in a form of a `pill` what i'm trying to accomplish is trying to add a `Unicode plus sign` inside of my pill something like this image below.

[image]

But whenever i try to increase the `font-size` of the Unicode it just messes up the whole text and shape of the pills is there any way to make it look like the image on-top without messing too much of the original css? Any help would be appreciated thanks.

```js
var red = {};
var key = "Red Fruits";
red[key] = ['Apple', 'Cherry', 'Strawberry', 'Pomegranate', 'Rassberry'];

var redString = '';
$.each(red[key], function(index) {
  redString += ('<div class="pilldiv redpill class">' + red[key][index] + '</div>');
});
$('.redclass').html(redString);
```

```css
.pilldiv {
    padding: 0px 19px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: Black;
    margin: 1px;
}
.redpill {
  background-color: Pink;
  cursor: default;
}

 .redpill:before {
    content: "\002B";
    font-size: 28px;
    width: 15px;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    margin-left: -7px;
}
.class {
  font-family: Open Sans;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrappingflexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

h3 {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: White;
}

.panel {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: black;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="panel">
    <div id="redid" class="redclass wrappingflexbox"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Use :before instead of :after, so that you don’t have to float it, so that you can then use vertical-align on it. If increasing the font size makes the whole pill thing too large for your taste, then try and counter that by reducing the padding.

Comment: @Bobby you must use `:after` maybe it be easier to use `<i>`

Comment: @CBroe May i ask if you can take alook at my updated codes above? i have made the change but now the text is not align.

Comment: Well then try a different value for `vertical-align`. (Easy enough to go through the possible values in your browser’s DOM inspector, to figure out which one will get you a result more to your liking.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the *actual* size of the pseudo-elememt font it will change the shape of the pill accordingly since the pill's size is determined by the size of the contents.

Thus I would suggest that you change the **apparent** size of the glyph by using a `transform` instead.

Since this is *entirely* visual it does not affect the size of the pill.

```
 .redpill:before {
    content: "\002B";
    /* font-size: 28px;*/ */ remove this */
    width: 15px;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    margin: 0 7px 0 -7px;
    display:inline-block; /* required */
    transform:scale(2); /* this*/
}
```

```js
var red = {};
var key = "Red Fruits";
red[key] = ['Apple', 'Cherry', 'Strawberry', 'Pomegranate', 'Rassberry'];

var redString = '';
$.each(red[key], function(index) {
  redString += ('<div class="pilldiv redpill class">' + red[key][index] + '</div>');
});
$('.redclass').html(redString);
```

```css
.pilldiv {
  padding: 0px 19px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: Black;
  margin: 1px;
}

.redpill {
  background-color: Pink;
  cursor: default;
}

.redpill:before {
  content: "\002B";
  /* font-size: 28px;*/
  */ remove this */ width: 15px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  margin: 0 7px 0 -7px;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: scale(2)
}

.class {
  font-family: Open Sans;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrappingflexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

h3 {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: White;
}

.panel {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: black;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="panel">
    <div id="redid" class="redclass wrappingflexbox"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `:before` inherits class `font-size`:

```
.redpill:before {
    content: "\002B";
    padding-right: 2px;
}

.pilldiv {
    padding: 5px 22px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: Black;
    margin: 1px;
}
```